# BigInteger to double incorrect rounding

Tags: c#, rounding, biginteger

I'm attempting to convert a BigInteger value to a double-precision value using the explicit cast operator in C#, but not getting the convergent rounding behavior I expected. I can't find any documentation on the rounding mode for this operation, but it doesn't match that of a long to double cast (which is also undocumented). Bug or feature? I've implemented my own rounding routine to work around it, but would rather stick with the built-in functionality.

Here's a test that passes as written (VS 2012 on Windows 7):

```
BigInteger roundMeDown = BigInteger.Pow(2, 53) + 1;
double expectedRoundedDown = Math.Pow(2, 53);

BigInteger roundMeUp = BigInteger.Pow(2, 53) + 3;
double expectedRoundedUp = Math.Pow(2, 53) + 4;
double actualResult = Math.Pow(2, 53) + 2;

Assert.AreEqual(expectedRoundedDown, (double)roundMeDown);

Assert.AreNotEqual(expectedRoundedUp, (double)roundMeUp);
Assert.AreEqual(actualResult, (double)roundMeUp);
```

Comment: The documentation merely states that the conversion is lossy, it doesn't document in what way it is specifically choosing to decide which `double` to use.  Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Why do you expect `BigInteger.Pow(2, 53) + 1 == Math.Pow(2, 53)` ?

Comment: Ahh, I get what you are trying to do :) Seems like a bug in the BigInteger to double conversion. Might have one of the reasons I dropped it from IronScheme and used IntX instead.

Comment: @Servy If the docs say it's un- or ill-defined, then he probably shouldn't rely on any behavior coming out of it... by doing this Microsoft basically just made that function useless IMO.  This raises the question as to why he is using BigInts in the first place if he is rounding to doubles at the end... is he running into rounding errors in intermediate calculations or something?

Comment: @CleverNeologism It means that the double value is now conceptually an approximation of the actual value.  You should *already* treat the double as an approximation of the value; it's inherent to the nature of `double`.  So long as you understand how to work with floating point numbers, the function isn't useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs

There's the actual source code, which will show you exactly how it does it.

In short, it looks like it basically chops and shifts, without any rounding occurring at all.  Note it calls a method called `GetApproxParts`.

However, it should be easy to hack on at the end if you need special rounding.

Basically, simply look at the `NumBits - 53`rd bit (from most to least significant) on the BigInteger using the `>>` and `|` operators (doubles have 52 bits in the mantissa).

There's basically three cases, and only the last is handled differently based on different rounding modes you might want to employ.

If the 53rd bit is not set, you don't need to round.

If it is, check the bits after it.  If any are set, round up (add Double.Epsilon).

If it is set and no bits after it are set, you are exactly in the middle of two valid double values.  Do whatever is reasonable, so long as it is consistent.

Comment: Not a bug really, as it's not against spec.

Comment: More info: You run into the same issue converting a ulong to a double in the core framework, and the run-time seems to handle that rounding just fine... I would expect all numeric types to operate in a similar fashion.  The default rounding mode in .NET is the normal rounding, with the midpoint being rounding to a zero bit.

Comment: Well it is wrong then! The laws of mathematics cannot be tweaked ;p I dont understand what you mean by the same 'issue' with ulong. It behaves just like long. https://gist.github.com/leppie/9ac1166a0172b44f3271 Everything prints true.

Comment: Also, there is nothing 'funny' going from `BigInteger` to `double`. Here is my simple naive and correct version (for `IntX`, but the same goes): https://github.com/leppie/IronScheme/blob/master/IronScheme/Oyster.IntX/IntX.cs#L1711

Comment: I'm implementing an arbitrary-precision library based on BigInteger, and as part of that I need a correctly-rounded cast from a higher precision float to a double. I agree that it's not technically wrong since they didn't document the rounding behavior, but not documenting a fundamental aspect of a numeric operation is also wrong. Sometimes you gotta take a stand...

Comment: @leppie No, it isn't wrong.  Truncation towards zero is a perfectly valid way to resolve rounding issues.

Comment: @Dolphin: You can just use my version if you want 'correct' behavior :)

Comment: @leppie You should consider looking at the BigInteger implementation of casting to double (of course, you'd add correct rounding).  Your routine does a ton of unnecessary double math on the low order bits... for example, with a 1024-bit integer, you're doing 64 fp multiplies...  shifting and testing would be faster.

Comment: @leppie: Thanks. I have something working, but it might be a bit lacking in the elegance and/or performance department. Lots of good ideas for improvements here!

Comment: Good point, but on the average case it should be 'fast' enough :)